# From tuple of N elements to tuple of N/2 pairs

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-hana

I would like to know, without using the typical recursive functions, but using `boost::hana` for example, how to transform in the simplest way with `boost` and `std` tools an object of the the following type (for example):

```
std::tuple<int, double, char, double>
```

to an object of type:

```
std::tuple<std::pair<int, double>, std::pair<char, double> >;
```

I was looking in the `boost::hana` documentation but I have found no easier way to do it than programming it manually with a recursive templated function (I have to say that there's hana's functions that I wasn't able to understood).

**NOTE:** What I had in mind initially was to create a range of integers from 0 to N (`hana::range`), then filtering them in two groups of even and odds indexes, and the getting, for each group of indexes, the corresponding values and apply a function over both lists in pairs to create the `std::pair`s... which are too much steps and can be achieved easier with a manual implementation; but I'm sure there's something that I have missed in the hana documentation.

Comment: I think the accepted answer is the best way to do it. You could use `hana::range` and `hana::unpack` to perhaps make this a little bit better looking, but it would be essentially the same.

Comment: @LouisDionne I've tried in different ways and the shortest way is: creating a `hana::range`, create a partition for odd and even indexes, and then `hana::unpack`  and `hana::zip_with` with a functor that creates the pairs. Other solution is to create a range from 0 to N/2, and then `hana::chain` or `hana::transform` to make the corresponding `*2` and `*2+1` operations on each, and `slice` twice for each index sequence. Too much pain...; the old style is still shorter.

Comment: Here's what I meant: https://wandbox.org/permlink/nLG7RC7ieZzK5io4. Like I said, it's more Hana-esque but it's otherwise essentially the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: @LouisDionne Yes I finally reach a similar approach but it is very cumbersome that one cannot simply do `hana::make_range(0, hana::size(tuple) / 2)` when every expression is constant here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without recursion, you can do:

```
template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
auto to_tuple_pairs(Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return make_tuple(std::make_pair(std::get<2 * Is>(tuple), std::get<2 * Is + 1>(tuple))...);
}

template <typename Tuple>
auto to_tuple_pairs(Tuple&& tuple)
{
    return to_tuple_pairs(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
                          std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value / 2>());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/413d44debb3d797f)

Comment: I think you need to multiply `Is` with 2 in the upper function to create the correct pairs.

Comment: @Banan: Indeed, fixed.